# System.TypeInitializationException:"Webservice.Helper.SqlHelper",System.NullReferenceException

Tags: sql, asp.net, winforms

Is it like configuration can't get data from the database?

Then what is the reason for the failure of server startup debugging? I've been checking for a long time and I hope you can save me

```
public static string sqlServierDBConnectString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["datazzj"].ConnectionString;
```

In addition to the place where the error was reported, there was this one：

```
    public string Login_GetUserID(string username,string pwd){
        string sqlText = @"SELECT UserId FROM [User_Shaoxie] WHERE userName=@userName and pwd = @pwd";
        SqlParameter[] _param={new SqlParameter("@userName",userName),new SqlParameter("@pwd",pwd)};
        Object obj;
        obj= SqlParameter.ExecuteScaler(SqlHelper.sqlServierDBConnectString,CommandType.Text,sqlText,_param);
        if(obj == DBNull.Value || obj == null){
           obj = "NoThisMan";}
        return obj.To String();
    }
```

Comment: is this at runtime or during unit test?

Comment: `new` is no valid C keyword. I changed C language tag to C++.

Comment: Errors at runtime